# oracle split comma delimited string into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like

```
Charge_num      mapping_col
---------       -----------
p1.pm.100       1.1.1,1000
p1.pm.110       1.2.1,1000
p1.pm.120       1.3.1,1000
```

I need to split the "mapping_col" into 2 columns like this:

```
Charge_num      wbs       obs
---------       ---       ---
p1.pm.100       1.1.1     1000
p1.pm.110       1.2.1     1000
p1.pm.120       1.3.1     1000
```

Comment: At first place, why do you store the data as delimited strings? You are violating **normalization**. Anyway, as a workaround, simply use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`. INSTR will return the position of comma `,` and then separate the substr based on that position. And remember, even with 12c, SUBSTR + INSTR approach is still faster than REGEX.

Comment: I didn't store it that way, but I have to write a report that pulls in data from that system.  When I first discovered this situation, my first cry was that it violated first normal form.

Comment: "*it violated first normal form*" Of course it violates the basic rules. Anyway, I guess, you could apply the workaround as of now. And, propose a design fix as permanent solution to  your organization. You could even create **virtual columns**. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
select charge_num, 
substr(mapping_col,1,instr(mapping_col,',',1)-1) AS first_half,
substr(mapping_col, instr(mapping_col,',',1)+1) as last_half
from your_table
```

Note that the practice of storing numbers as strings is prone to error.  If you were to cast these results as NUMBER(9) it could break unpredictably if your data is irregular

Comment: "*Note that the practice of storing numbers as strings is prone to error. If you were to cast these results as NUMBER(9) it could break unpredictably if your data is irregular*" Well, I do agree to certain extent with you. However, there are exceptions. Note that a lot of countries follow certain norms for their data, due to which you are bound to store data as delimited string.

Answer (score 2):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` to the rescue!

```
with sample_data as (select 'p1.pm.100' charge_num, '1.1.1,1000' mapping_col from dual union all
                     select 'p1.pm.110' charge_num, '1.2.1,1000' mapping_col from dual union all
                     select 'p1.pm.120' charge_num, '1.3.1,1000' mapping_col from dual)
select charge_num,
       regexp_substr(mapping_col, '[^,]+', 1, 1) wbs,
       regexp_substr(mapping_col, '[^,]+', 1, 2) obs
from   sample_data;

CHARGE_NUM WBS                            OBS                           
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
p1.pm.100  1.1.1                          1000                          
p1.pm.110  1.2.1                          1000                          
p1.pm.120  1.3.1                          1000
```

Comment: The performance of regular expressions are obviously getting better with each newer releases. +1